# Handling an onclick event; uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, onclick, html5-canvas

I'm having an issue here that I can't seem to find the solution too. I'm trying to handle an onclick event that just switches around the colors on a "tile". Here is the script that I have to do so:

```
<script>
    var GameTile = {
        createTile : function() {
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.id = "tileContainer";
            newElement.style.width = "100px";
            newElement.style.height = "100px";
            newElement.setAttribute("onclick", "GameTile.convertColor()");
            document.body.appendChild(newElement)

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "tileCanvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("width", "100");
            canvas.setAttribute("height", "100");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 100, 100);

            ctx.fillStyle = "#969696";
            ctx.fillRect (7, 7, 86, 86);
            document.getElementById("tileContainer").appendChild(canvas);

        },

        convertColor : function() { 

            var canvas = document.getElementById('tileCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContex("2d");

            ctx.fillStyle = "#969696";
            ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 100, 100);

            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect (7, 7, 86, 86);

            document.getElementById("tileContainer").appendChild(canvas);
        }

    };
</script>
```

As far as I can tell the function convertColor() is actually defined, am I calling it incorrectly? Or is my actual syntax incorrect?

Comment: where is it saying uncaught type error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo in the convertColor function.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContex("2d");
```

it should be

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

notice the missing t.

Comment: I do! Thank you so very much! I spend about 3 hours looking over this code and I didn't even see that. Thank you very much for catching that. Everything works fine now. =D

Answer (score 0):

You should swap this

```
newElement.setAttribute("onclick", "GameTile.convertColor()");
```

to this

```
newElement.addEventListener("click", "GameTile.convertColor()");
```